# My network adapters can't detect 802.11a radio wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter

I have two adapters, one has the Atheros AR9002WB-1NG and  the other is a LAN USB Adapter #4. For some reason or the other they both can't detect 802.11a connections. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: What OS are you using?  Are you using the driver & the default OS utility to configure the network, or are you using the utility included with the drivers?

Comment: Your LAN USB Adapter is unlikely even a wireless adapater based on the name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the one it is obvious: the [AR9002WB-1NG](http://www.qca.qualcomm.com/technology/technology.php?nav1=47&product=75) is a 2.4GHz-only chipset, so it cannot see the 802.11a network which operates at 5GHz.

As for the `LAN USB Adapter #4` - it won't be possible to tell if it supports 5GHz unless you can find out the chipset, but I suspect it's also 2.4GHz only since you say it can't detect your 802.11a network either.